# Issue during 'roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch'

Tags: gazebo, turtlebot, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody!

I have Ubuntu 16.06 Xenial and ROS Kinetic installed. I want to launch gazebo turtlebot simulation with a command:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch
```

At first, I installed turtlebot using:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot ros-kinetic-turtlebot-apps ros-kinetic-turtlebot-interactions ros-kinetic-turtlebot-simulator ros-kinetic-kobuki-ftdi ros-kinetic-rocon-remocon ros-kinetic-rocon-qt-library ros-kinetic-ar-track-alvar-msgs
```

Then launching gazebo turtlebot simulation I got a typical error:

```
[turtlebot_world.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot_gazebo] nor is [turtlebot_gazebo] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

After that I installed without deleting the previous turtlebot software:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-turtlebot-gazebo
```

Everything was fine and then I tried again and got:

```
..

. logging to /home/aleks/.ros/log/98e51c20-20bd-11e8-91d8-ccb0dacbc15b/roslaunch-aleks-Aspire-E5-575G-15388.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

Invalid <arg> tag: environment variable 'TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE' is not set
.
Arg xml is <arg default="$(env TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE)" name="world_file"/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/284506/issue-during-%27roslaunch-turtlebot_gazebo-turtlebot_world.launch%27/) by [Chput](https://answers.ros.org/users/33949/chput/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2018-03-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aliu04](https://answers.ros.org/users/50935/aliu04/) on 2020-01-15**:
HI there, I just met the same question, and I followed the instruction to set the source, still cannot run the program, could you please give me some advice??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Completely forgot to `source devel/setup.bash`
Issue solved.

---

Originally posted by [Chput](https://answers.ros.org/users/33949/chput/) with karma: 48 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=TURTLEBOT_GAZEBO_WORLD_FILE) gave me #q208287. In that answer, @130s stated

> Turtlebot utilizes environment variables that are set by env hook. See [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Turtlebot%20Installation#Environment_variables).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-03-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2